# Monero Wallet GUI cannot be opened in MacOS Catalina

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, macos

[image: MacOS error message upon trying to open the wallet]

Hi, I am trying to install the Monero Wallet GUI on my Mac (with latest OS Catalina 10.15.6), but after downloading, and I assume installing, when I double click the on the wallet icon (After adding exceptions to the two antivurs warnings) I get the following pop up from MacOS Catalina stating it cannot be opened.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Many Thanks

Comment: Which specific version of the GUI did you download?

Comment: monero-gui-mac-x64-v0.16.0.3.dmg

Comment: Which AV software do you use?

Comment: Really don't know how to get around this other than disable AntiVirus.
I disabled this and can open up the App fine :-)
I did notice that there is a new version coming out v17.0, but it looks like only the CLI wallet is there, so I will continue installing the v16.0.3 version of the GUI.
Thanks dEBRUYNE for your assistance.